# Java Regular Expression Skipping Character sequence while splitting

Tags: java, regex

I have a string  which containe multiple id and their names:

---

1019-Rice Distribution/1022- Wheat (Supplement)/1030-Rice BPLCVC (SLETY)/1031-Rice BPLCVC Adhoc (For K-35)

---

I want to split it and store it in another string array 
when I use

```
 myString.split("[/or-]");
```

It gives me almost desired result. But there is one problem when in last combination where program name contains "-", programme splits this also which I don't want 
How to avoid this. Please suggest a general solution which work for program name like J-300 also not only for K-35
Desired output

- 1019   Rice Distribution
- 1031   Wheat (Supplement)
- 1030   Rice BPLCVC (SLETY)
- 1031   Rice BPLCVC Adhoc (For K-35)

Comment: Please provide the desired output.

Comment: It looks like you want to split on `/` and later replace `-` that is after `xxxx` where `x` is digit.

Comment: @AvinashSahu you want to get an array as result with **8** elements or **4**? you said in your question, your regex gave **almost desired result**, besides the `-` in name case, it will give **8** elements right? but your desired output from you previous edit, has only **4** elements?

Comment: @Kent Sorry for confusion. I got the desired result using few answers here. Anyway thanks for your response and time.

Answer (score 1):

I would split at `/` first to get an array of ID/name-pairs and then part each string via `substring` and `indexOf` at the first `-` to get ID and name separately.

Answer (score 1):

don't know if this is ok for you:

```
String s = "yourString";
String[] v = s.split("/|(?<=(/|^)\\d{1,999})-");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v));
```

it outputs:

```
[1019, Rice Distribution, 1022,  Wheat (Supplement), 1030, Rice BPLCVC (SLETY), 1031, Rice BPLCVC Adhoc (For K-35)]
```

so you see the last element, `k-35` is there.

Answer (score 1):

```
String bubba = "1019-Rice Distribution/1022- Wheat (Supplement)/1030-Rice BPLCVC (SLETY)/1031-Rice BPLCVC Adhoc (For K-35)";

for(String c: bubba.split("/"){
 System.out.println(c.replaceFirst("-"," ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would be a little more sophisticated and use a `Pattern` to extract each `key -> value` pair:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String in = "1019-Rice Distribution/1022- Wheat (Supplement)/1030-Rice BPLCVC (SLETY)/1031-Rice BPLCVC Adhoc (For K-35)";
    final Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("(\\d++)\\s*+-\\s*+([^/]++)(/|$)");
    final Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(in);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + " -> " + matcher.group(2));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1019 -> Rice Distribution
1022 -> Wheat (Supplement)
1030 -> Rice BPLCVC (SLETY)
1031 -> Rice BPLCVC Adhoc (For K-35)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to split on `/` and replace `-` after first 4 digits with space. If that is true then you can try this something like:

```
String data = "1019-Rice Distribution/1022- Wheat (Supplement)/1030-Rice BPLCVC (SLETY)/1031-Rice BPLCVC Adhoc (For K-35)";
for (String s : data.split("/"))
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?<=^\\d{4})-\\s*", " "));
```

output:

```
1019 Rice Distribution
1022 Wheat (Supplement)
1030 Rice BPLCVC (SLETY)
1031 Rice BPLCVC Adhoc (For K-35)
```

Explanation:

In `replaceAll("(?<=^\\d{4})-\\s*", " ")`

- `(?<=...)` is look behind mechanism. It tests if right before place regex cursor is there was substring which matches regex described in look behind, in out case `^\\d{4}` four digits placed at start of string. Most important part about it is that substring matched by look behind will not be included in actual match (the one in group 0).
- `-\\s*` is part we want to replace with space, which is one `-` and optionally some more spaces like in case of `1022- Wheat (Supplement)`